# Jquery form Validation - equalTo not working?

Tags: html, jquery

I want the user to confirm the password. I have used Jquery's validate function to validate the form. After entering the correct password, it shows me an error as **Password not Match !**.

In hmtl:

```
  <form class="form-password" id="formId" method="POST"> 
            <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control bsdbsdhdhu" placeholder="Enter Old Password">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bsdbsdhdhu" name="new_password" placeholder="Enter New Password">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bsdbsdhdhu" name="retype_password" placeholder="Enter Re-enter Password">
            <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

In .js:

```
jQuery('#formId').validate({
    rules: {
        old_password: {
            required: true,
        },
        new_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
        },
        retype_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            equalTo: '#new_password',
        }
    },
    messages: {
        old_password: {
            required: 'Please Enter Old Password',
        },
        new_password: {
            required: 'Please Enter New Password',
            minlength: 'Password length must be 8',
        },
        retype_password: {
            required: 'Please Retype Password',
            minlength: 'Password Lenght Must be 8',
            equalTo: 'Password Not Matched !',
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given the id to the new_password input field and then it's working.